# .net 7 api auto scale function not working

Tags: azure, .net-7.0

I have an .NET 7 REST API which has singleton class initialization.

It is working fine with single instance, and it fails with multiple instances.

Below is my singleton initialization.

```cs
Engine _engine = new Engine(loggerFactory);
builder.Services.AddSingleton<Engine>(_engine);
```

This functionality mainly deletes/load folder to the **wwwroot** directory.

Could someone give me a solution on making use of multiple instances with singleton class.

Comment: Er... Singletons don't scale that's kind of the point of them.

Answer (score 0):

> could someone give me a solution on making use of multiple instances with singleton class.

Ensuring to run only single instance of the Azure Function App runs at a time is the responsibility of `SingletonAttribute` class.

This class also other feature in limiting the instances count that runs at that time and that impacts the scalability and performance.

That feature is the `Mode` property of the `FunctionInvocation` attribute and the syntax is:

`Mode = Function / Listener`

```
[Singleton(Mode = SingletonMode.Listener)]
[FunctionName("ListenerTest")]
```

If the mode property is `Listener`, then it does the single instance execution and `Function` mode can give you run multiple instances and simultaneous executions but ensures that only one instance processes a given function invocation at a time.

Refer to this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-sdk-how-to#singleton-attribute) and medium [article](https://medium.com/@yuka1984/azure-functions-%E3%81%AE-singletonattribute%E3%81%A8mode%E3%83%97%E3%83%AD%E3%83%91%E3%83%86%E3%82%A3-bb728062198e) by the author @yu_ka1984 for more information on using the `SingletonAttribute` - `FunctionInvocation` - `Mode` for running the multiple instances.

Comment: Hari Krishna, I'm using .net 7 web api and not Azure Http trigger function

Comment: Oh my bad, This Singleton attribute support is in open state for the Azure functions (Out-of-process) model as mentioned in this GitHub Issue [274](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/issues/274)

Answer (score 0):

Issue is fixed by dropping the files under the machine name

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).